# Display Jenkins Job test result in Github Pull Request PR

Tags: github, jenkins

I am trying to display smoke test results (pass/fail) from Jenkins in git checks whenever there is a PR submitted. Basically, when someone submits a pull request, the status in git is pending while we run smoke test on Jenkins and change the status to pass or fail in git depending on the smoke test results.

The desired output is something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using GitHub App Authentication with Jenkins integration.